# How to enable Application Timeline in visual studio 2017 C++ project?

Tags: performance, time, visual-studio-2017

I would like to analyze my C++ program in order to find out which function is taking a lot of time.
I wanted to use the Application Timeline in VS 2017 (professional) Performance Profiler, but it seems to be disabled.
How can I enable it? or perhaps there's another suggested tool?
Thanks
[image]